# Using SSHA via pam_ldap on CentOS authenticating against ApacheDS

Tags: apache-2.2, ldap, pam

I'm struggling to get CentOS to authenticate users via ApacheDS when the userPassword is encrypted with SSHA or SHA. Crypt works fine but due to restrictions of other services I really need this authd by SSHA.

Has anyone else had this problem? I'm sure I'm missing something but I can't see a value to set for allowing pam_ldap to authd by SSHA.

Cheers,
-Ed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, I figured out what the problem was.

You can authenticate just fine using {crypt} in userPassword for a posixAccount even if you don't add in the relevant changes to /etc/pam.d/system-auth. I was thrown off by this.

Once I added:

```
auth        sufficient    pam_ldap.so use_first_pass
account     sufficient    pam_ldap.so
password    sufficient    pam_ldap.so ssha use_authtok use_first_pass
session     optional      pam_ldap.so
```

It worked just fine against {SHA} and {SSHA} encrypted userPassword in each posixAccount.

Also, oddly enough doing `getent shadow <user>` will only show the password if you have a {crypt} encrypted userPassword in the posixAccount. It never shows up for anything else.

Cheers,
-Ed